# JavaFX - Feedback on successful registration

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scene

I am currently working on a project with databases and JavaFX.
However, I want the user to get feedback upon successful registration in a different scene.

Let's say the user registers, the registration is successful, so the user gets redirected to the login-scene (Login.fxml). Here I want a simple label to say "You have been successfully registered".

How do I go about solving this? Is threading a viable option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you have tried already and where the issue is arising?  That way we can provide a little more help.

Comment: You can use ControlsFX Notifications or you can use a JavaFx Alert. I suggest JavaFx alert because it's built in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example of how you can handle a successful/failed states. If the action is successful an alert pops up stating so. Once the user click the OK button then you should load your fxml. The code alert.showAndWait() shows the alert and waits for the user to press the OK button or close the alert. After alert.showAndWait() is where you need to load your new fxml.

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        boolean regSuccessful = random.nextBoolean();

        if(regSuccessful)
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Registration Status:");
            alert.setContentText("You have successfully registered!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            //load the fxml need here!
            System.out.println("loading fxml!");
            label.setText("loading fxml!");
        }
        else
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.setTitle("Registration Status:");
            alert.setContentText("Registration failed!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            label.setText("registration failed!");
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication53.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication53 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use thread. For example;

```
Platform.runLater(() -> successfullyRegistered());
```